# Problems during file sending

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram

The user sends the name of the file to be found, the fd function returns the final path to the file in an array, in this format ['C:\Users\vlash\Documents\test1.txt'].   When send_document is called, the found path is passed, the function executes, but nothing happens, the file is not sent to the chat with the user.

```
@router.message(WorkFind.find)
async def find(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer(
        f'Ask'
    )
    path1 = [f"C:\\Users\\vlash\\Documents"]
    data = message.text
    if len(fd(path1, data)) > 0:
        for i in fd(path1, data):
            try:
                await message.bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Good answer")
                await message.bot.send_document(
                    chat_id = message.from_user.id,
                    document=FSInputFile(path = i),
                    caption = "231231231231")
                # await message.bot.send_document(chat_id=message.from_user.id, )
            except:
                await message.bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "K.O.")
    else:
        await message.bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAA')

    await message.bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Compliete")
    await state.clear() 

FSInputFile into the variable. Manually entered the path to the file and its name.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better of passing the file itself:

```
with open(i, 'rb') as file:
    await message.bot.send_document (
        chat_id = message.from_user.id,
        document=file,
        caption = "231231231231"
    )
```